# How to find the line number in which something occurs?

Tags: python, zip, text-files, enumerate

I was trying to create a program which tells me in a given text if there are 2 adjacent words which are the same and where in the text file does this happen( line and word number). So far I have been able to determine which word number but can't seem to figure out which line it happens in. Would anyone be able to give me a hand please? So far, next to the Error/ No Error, I  am able to get the word number but if I could just get the line number as well.

```
for line in (textfile):
    for x, y in enumerate(zip(line.split(), line.split()[1:])):
```

Comment: `for line_number, line in enumerate(textfile): ...` should work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply use `enumerate` again in the outer loop?

```
for line_number, line in enumerate(textfile):
    for x, y in enumerate(zip(line.split(), line.split()[1:])):
        if(x,y)==(y,x):
            print(line_number,x,y,"Error")
        else:
            print(line_number,x,y,"No error")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a counter where you establish an integer and add 1 to the integer every time you iterate over a line. For example:

```py
file_name = "whatever.txt"
textfile = open(file_name, "r")
line_number = 0 # this integer will store the line number
for line in (textfile):
    line_number += 1
    for x, y in enumerate(zip(line.split(), line.split()[1:])):
        if(x,y)==(y,x):
            print(x,y,"Error")
        else:
            print(x,y,"No error")
```